# Add class to one SPECIFIC menu item

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm looking for a way to add an extra class to a specific menu item in my main menu. I see ways to add classes to the entire menu, but not one specfic item.  Can someone point me in the correct direction.

This is for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to install [Menu Attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes).

> The module currently allows you to set the following attributes for
>   each menu item: Id, Name, Target, Rel, Class, Style, Accesskey

Comment: I looked at this module, but it seems to apply to all menu items.  I want to apply an extra class to a specific menu item.

Comment: Well it shouldnt. See this video by its author (i've jumped to the relevant part at 1:40 for you) http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=OPGFwhpvqbw#!&t=1m40s

Comment: sure no problem. you may want to "accept" the answer if it meets your needs so others know its a valid solution without reading through comments.

Comment: I tried, but looks like I can't accept answers.